WP Update Messages get cut off during Theme update
I created a custom class for updating my custom theme. It has been working well for several months but the usual WordPress messages during upgrade get cut off when any upgrade process is running.

The image shows where the messages stop.
Here's my class:
<?php defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 *  THEME UPDATER
 *
 *  @package WordPress
 *  @since ToongeePrime Theme 1.0.55
 *  https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/recommended-usage-of-the-updates-api-to-support-the-auto-updates-ui-for-plugins-and-themes-in-wordpress-5-5
 */

class Prime2gThemeUpdater {
    public
        $theme,
        $slug   =   PRIME2G_TEXTDOM,
        $current_version;
    protected
        $transient_name =   'prime_transient_update_theme',
        $metadataUrl    =   'https://pathtothememetadata.com/theme.json';



    public function __construct() {
        if ( defined( 'PRIMETHEMEUPDATER' ) ) return;
        define( 'PRIMETHEMEUPDATER', true );

        $this->theme            =   wp_get_theme( $this->slug );
        $this->current_version  =   $this->theme->get( 'Version' );

        $this->maybe_clear_transients();

        $this->set_this_theme_transient();

        $this->admin_notices();

        add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', [ $this,'set_theme_status_response' ] );
        add_filter( 'site_transient_update_themes', [ $this,'set_update_notice' ] );

        $this->upgrade_processing();

        add_action( 'deleted_site_transient', [ $this, 'delete_transient_if' ], 10, 1 );
    }



    private function update_available() {
        $update_data    =   get_site_transient( $this->transient_name );
        if ( ! $update_data || isset( $update_data->error ) && $update_data->error === true )
            return false;
        return version_compare( $this->current_version, $update_data->version, '<' );
    }


    /**
     *  Retrieve update info from metadata URL
     */
    private function get_remote_data() {
        $remote =   wp_remote_get(
            $this->metadataUrl,
            array(
            'timeout'   =>  10,
            'headers'   =>  [ 'Accept' => 'application/json' ]
            )
        );

        $remote_body    =   wp_remote_retrieve_body( $remote );

        if ( is_wp_error( $remote ) || 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $remote )
            || empty( $remote_body ) ) {
            return (object) [ 'error' => true, 'message' => 'Failed remote request' ];
        }

        return  json_decode( $remote_body );
    }


    /**
     *  Establish workings within this class
     */
    private function set_this_theme_transient() {
        if ( $remote_to_transient = get_site_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
            return $remote_to_transient;
        }
        else {
            $remote_to_transient    =   $this->get_remote_data();

            if ( isset( $remote_to_transient->error )
            && $remote_to_transient->error === true ) return;

            set_site_transient( $this->transient_name, $remote_to_transient, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            return $remote_to_transient;
        }
    }


    private function transient_item_data() {
    $remote_in_transient    =   get_site_transient( $this->transient_name );

    if ( ! $remote_in_transient ) {
        return  [
            'theme'         =>  $this->slug,
            'new_version'   =>  $this->current_version,
            'url'           =>  '',
            'package'       =>  '',
            'requires'      =>  '',
            'requires_php'  =>  ''
        ];
    }

    return  array(
        'theme'         =>  $this->slug,
        'new_version'   =>  $this->update_available() ? $remote_in_transient->version : $this->current_version,
        'url'           =>  $remote_in_transient->details_url,
        'package'       =>  $remote_in_transient->download_url,
        'requires'      =>  $remote_in_transient->requires,
        'requires_php'  =>  $remote_in_transient->requires_php
    );
    }


    private function update_qualified() {
    $remote_in_transient    =   get_site_transient( $this->transient_name );

    return version_compare( $remote_in_transient->requires, get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '<=' )
        && version_compare( $remote_in_transient->requires_php, PHP_VERSION, '<=' );
    }


    /**
     *  Callback @ pre_set_site_transient_update_themes
     */
    function set_theme_status_response( $transient ) {
    $item_data  =   $this->transient_item_data();

        if ( $this->update_available() && $this->update_qualified() ) {
            $transient->response[ $this->slug ] =   $item_data;
        }
        else {
            $transient->no_update[ $this->slug ]=   $item_data;
        }
    return $transient;
    }


    /**
     *  Callback @ site_transient_update_themes
     */
    function set_update_notice( $transient ) {
    if ( is_object( $transient ) ) {
        $transient  =   $this->set_theme_status_response( $transient );
    }
    else {
        //  Fix for warning messages on Dashboard / Updates page
        $transient  =   new stdClass();
        $item_data  =   $this->transient_item_data();
        $transient->response    =   $transient->no_update   =   [];
        $transient->response[ $this->slug ]     =   $item_data;
        $transient->no_update[ $this->slug ]    =   $item_data;
    }
    return $transient;
    }


    function upgrade_processing() {
    if ( wp_doing_ajax() || ! is_admin() || ! current_user_can( 'update_themes' ) ) return;

        // inspired by ET_Core_Updates->remove_theme_update_actions()
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
            remove_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', [ $this, 'set_theme_status_response' ] );
            remove_filter( 'site_transient_update_themes', [ $this, 'set_update_notice' ] );
        }, 11 );

        add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', function( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
            if ( $options['action'] === 'update'
            && $options['type'] === 'theme' && isset( $options['themes'] ) ) {
                foreach( $options['themes'] as $theme ) {
                    if ( $theme === $this->slug ) { set_site_transient( 'p2gtheme_updated', 1 ); }
                }
            }
        }, 10, 2 );
    }


    private function admin_notices() {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
    global $pagenow;

        if ( $this->update_available() && ! in_array( $pagenow, [ 'update-core.php', 'themes.php' ] ) && current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
            echo '<div class="notice notice-warning notice-alt is-dismissible">
            <p>'. __( 'New ToongeePrime Theme Update is available, please update now ', $this->slug ) .'
            <a href="'. admin_url( 'update-core.php?prime-update=theme' ) .'" title="Update the theme here">'. __( 'here', $this->slug ) .'</a>!
            </p></div>';
        }

        if ( get_site_transient( 'p2gtheme_updated' ) ) {
            echo '<div class="notice notice-success notice-alt is-dismissible"><p>'
            . __( 'Thanks for updating the Theme, ToongeePrime!', $this->slug ) .
            '</p></div>';
            delete_site_transient( 'p2gtheme_updated' );
        }

    } );
    }


    private function maybe_clear_transients() {
    if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) return;
    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can( 'update_themes' ) && isset( $_GET[ 'prime-update' ] ) ) {
    $action     =   $_GET[ 'prime-update' ];

        if ( in_array( $action, [ 'clear-caches', 'clear-transients' ] ) ) {
            if ( get_site_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
                $deleted    =   delete_site_transient( $this->transient_name );
                wp_clean_themes_cache();
                if ( $deleted ) {
                    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
                    echo '<div class="notice notice-warning notice-alt is-dismissible">
                    <p>'. __( 'Themes updates transients have been cleared!', $this->slug ) .'</p></div>';
                    } );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $action === 'theme' ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
            echo '<div class="notice notice-warning notice-alt is-dismissible">
            <p>'. __( 'To Clear transients and Re-check update availability, ', $this->slug ) .'
            <a href="'. admin_url( 'update-core.php?prime-update=clear-caches' ) .'" title="Check again">'. __( 'click here', $this->slug ) .'</a>.
            </p></div>';
            } );
        }

    }
    }


    function delete_transient_if( $deleted_transient ) {
    if ( $deleted_transient === 'update_themes' )
        delete_site_transient( $this->transient_name );
    }

}



/**
 *      ACTIVATE
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'prime2g_theme_updater' ) ) {

add_action( 'admin_init', 'prime2g_theme_updater' );
function prime2g_theme_updater() {
    new Prime2gThemeUpdater();
}

}


All is well asides the messages being cut off... and that's what I need help about.

Okay... so ever since I posted this question I have been monitoring it on various of my client websites and noticed that it actually works perfectly on some hosting plans while this error persists on the sites using the same hosting plan where this issue persisted - so it seems to be a hosting issue.

Now, I've found what the real issues was... I had output buffering in the theme using this code if ( ! isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' ] ) ) { ob_start(); } elseif ( strpos( ' ' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' ], 'x-gzip' ) === false ) {  if ( strpos( ' ' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' ], 'gzip' ) === false ) { ob_start(); }  elseif ( ! ob_start( "ob_gzhandler" ) ) { ob_start(); } } elseif ( ! ob_start( "ob_gzhandler" ) ) { ob_start(); }
Upon removing the code, the updating process is just fine.
